# When is there a complex logarithm?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a no-where zero holomorphic function $f(z)$ on $V$, which is an open set of $\mathbb{C}$. Under what condition on $V$ can I guarantee to find a holomorphic function
(on $V$) $L(z)$ such that $e^{L(z)} = f(z)$? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$V$ must be simply connected.

If it's simply connected, there are no loops containing holes, so there is no problem consistently sticking to a single branch of the logarithm.

If it's not simply connected, simply pick $f(z) = z - a$ to have a zero in a hole, and so the logarithm has to have a branch cut.